# Probability of drawing red cards

Tags: probability

> A standard deck of cards consists of 26 red cards (hearts and diamonds) and 26 black cards (clubs and spades).  Suppose you shuffle such a deck and draw three cards at random without replacement.  Let $A_i =$ the event that the $i$th card is a red card, for $i = 1, 2, 3$.  Mark each of the following statements as TRUE or FALSE.
>
> (a) $P(A_2)> P(A_1)$
>
> (b) $A_1$ and $A_3$ are independent.
>
> (c) $P(A_1|A_3)< P(A_1)$

I'm having a lot of trouble with part a. Obviously $P(A_1)$ is $26/52$, but $P(A_2)$ is either ($26/51$) or ($25/51$) depending on what happened in $A_1$.

Comment: Actually, $P(A_2) = 26/52$. For an intuitive answer, look at my related answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657367/intuitive-reason-why-sampling-without-replacement-doesnt-change-expectation/1657373#1657373). Also, are you looking for answers or hints for b) and c)?

Comment: Formally, $P(A_2) = P(A_1 \cap A_2) + P(A_1^c \cap A_2) = \cdots.$

Comment: @Max ohhh, now I see, we're going to be drawing the three cards first, and THEN looking at them all at the same time. I was assuming that we would be drawing them one at a time.

Comment: And yes, I would appreciate answers or hints for b and c as well. I thought they were straightforward, but I see now that my logic was flawed for the entire problem.

Comment: Whether you draw them together or one at a time can make no difference. However, if $A_i$ happens, it slightly reduces the chance of $A_j$ happening (for $i \neq j$, of course).

Comment: I meant that I thought we would be drawing the first card and looking at whether it was red or black before drawing the second card.

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN: Even if you look at the cards, it makes no difference. If the first card is red, **you** know that the second is more likely to be black, but that has no effect on the probability when computed over **all** possible permutations of cards.

Comment: So $A_1$ and $A_3$ are independent, correct?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN: No, look at the answer below. Intuitively they can't  be, if $A_3$ happens, this affects the probability of $A_1$ having happened since there are fewer red than black cards. The formal demonstration is below.

Comment: Wow you're right, sorry. I only saw the first answer. Your answer clears it up perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Each permutation of the deck is equally likely. When you select the three cards, each one is equally likely to be red or black from which the probablity
follows (${1 \over 2}$).

Hence $pA_1 p A_3 = {1 \over 4}$, however $p (A_1 \text{ and } A_3) = { \binom{26}{2}\over \binom{52}{2}} = {25 \cdot 26 \over 51 \cdot 52 } = {25 \over 102} < {1 \over 4}$.

Intuitively, if you know that $A_3$ occurred, there are fewer red cards than black cards remaining, hence the chance of $A_1$ being red is lessened slightly. It is easy to compute $p [A_1 | A_3] = { p (A_1 \text{ and } A_3) \over p A_3} = {50 \over 102} < {1 \over 2}$

Answer (score 0):

The formal answer is that the first card is red or black with probability $\frac 12$.  The probability the second card is red is then $\frac{25}{51} \cdot \frac 12$ (first card is red) + $\frac{26}{51} \cdot \frac 12$ (first card is black)$=\frac 12$, so it is false.  The intuitive answer is to draw the two cards.  Clearly $P(A_1)=\frac 12$.  Before you look at them, swap them.  Now $P(A_2)=\frac 12$.  Done.